# Detect EXIF Orientation and Rotate Image using ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, exif

Canon DSLRs appear to save photos in landscape orientation and uses `exif::orientation` to do the rotation.

**Question:** How can imagemagick be used to re-save the image into the intended orientation using the exif orientation data such that it no longer requires the exif data to display in the correct orientation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php Extract the rotation parameter, test it, rotate image if need be.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use the [auto-orient](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option of ImageMagick's `convert` to do this.

```
convert your-image.jpg -auto-orient output.jpg
```

Or use `mogrify`to do it in place

```
mogrify -auto-orient your-image.jpg
```

Comment: Don't forget you can use `mogrify` instead of `convert` if you want to replace the existing file (in-place), which is useful when you want to do a directory full.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in all cases. I have at least a case that GIMP asks me if I want to fix the rotation, but convert just leaves the image as it is (leaving the real upper part of the picture in the right part).

Comment: If you’re into *libvps*: `vips autorot your-image.jpg output.jpg`

See function lists: https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/func-list.html#function-list

Comment: `convert` and `mogrify` can (and do) reduce your file size, and therefore your resolution.

Comment: Note that this will not update the ExifImageHeight/ExifImageWidth or rotate the internal thumbnail.

Answer (score 58):

The PHP Imagick way would be to test the image orientation and rotate/flip the image accordingly:

```
function autorotate(Imagick $image)
{
    switch ($image->getImageOrientation()) {
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT:
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPRIGHT:
        $image->flopImage();
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT:
        $image->rotateImage("#000", 180);
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMLEFT:
        $image->flopImage();
        $image->rotateImage("#000", 180);
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTTOP:
        $image->flopImage();
        $image->rotateImage("#000", -90);
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP:
        $image->rotateImage("#000", 90);
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTBOTTOM:
        $image->flopImage();
        $image->rotateImage("#000", 90);
        break;
    case Imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM:
        $image->rotateImage("#000", -90);
        break;
    default: // Invalid orientation
        break;
    }
    $image->setImageOrientation(Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
}
```

The function might be used like this:

```
$img = new Imagick('/path/to/file');
autorotate($img);
$img->stripImage(); // if you want to get rid of all EXIF data
$img->writeImage();
```

Comment: This solution works! I've only tried 1 image and there are of course 8, but I'll let you know how it goes. For me it was rotateImage, ->rotate just breaks

Comment: Thanks, fixed the `rotateImage` stuff.  If you want to test all orientations: There is a neat [github repo](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples) which has an image for each exif value.

Comment: thanks! worked in c#. i just needed a little conversion.

Answer (score 3):

`mogrify` and `convert` both will lossy resize the image when correcting the orientation.

Use `exiftran` instead for lossless rotation.

On nice feature of `exiftran` is it's inplace flag (`-i`) allows you to process an entire directory at once, combined with the "auto" `-a` flag, like this:

```
exiftran -ai *.jpg
```

Comment: `exiftran` changed image dimensions 48x100 -> 50x100 on this input file:
- https://mcc.id.au/2020/image-orientation/arrow-with-orientation.jpg

Comment: The image you provided is 100x50, and when I ran `exiftran -ai arrow-with-orientation.jpg`, it switched the orientation and dimensions were 50x100