# How can i determine distorted images with php imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I have normal and distorted images in project. I need to correctly resize only distorted images

How can I check if image is distorted or not with `imagick`? Is there any `imagick` properties which can help me?

Distorted image examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you define a distorted image?

Comment: Distorted images was made by some code that changed original images. Maybe  distorted images was made by changing orientation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456036/detect-exif-orientation-and-rotate-image-using-imagemagick (i used code from second answer to get correct image orientation)

Comment: Images was defined like this:
$imagick = new \Imagick(BASE_PATH . '/uploads' . $image->filename);
$imagick->resizeimage($newWidth, $newHeight,  0.9, TRUE);
$imagick->writeimage($absCacheName);

Comment: How do define a distorted image compared to an image that has just had its orientation corrected? (*hint* - I'm not asking this just to be annoying, your original question isn't answerable without defining this.)

Answer (score 1):

The method signature is: [Imagick::resizeImage ( int $columns , int $rows , int $filter , float $blur [, bool $bestfit = false ] )](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

You are missing the filter parameter, as so the image is being resized without preserving the aspect ratio.

Try passing in \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS as the filter parameter.

Comment: Ok, i got it. But question is a little bit different. If i have a lot of images already resized and some images incorrectly resized, can i detect which images was resized correctly, and which not? I need this check to resize back only distorted, incorrect images, not all images.

Comment: "can i detect which images was resized correctly, and which not?" - probably not, not unless you can define what distorted means. If it's just your code that's mangled the images, I suggest just figuring out by hand which images that applies to. I don't believe Imagick stores flags for whether images have been resized in images.