# PHP Image rotation

Tags: php, image

hey guy's i have a little issue...

i have an image up loader that works great on the PC, moves-resize-thumbnail all.

but.the issue is when i use the cell to upload it rotates the image 90 degrees..

i read that it is a common issue with phones...

So i need to make an editor to rotate the image by user..so if he uses the cell he edits the image to rotate correctly...

is it possible to does this?

i seem lots of image rotaters but when it uploads not in edit?

here is my code:

```
   session_start();
include_once 'config/dbconnect.php';


if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if(is_array($_FILES)) {


           $User=$_POST['User'];
           //$product_name=$_POST['Name'];
           $product_desc=$_POST['Desc'];
           $product_date_exp=$_POST['Exp'];
           $product_qty=$_POST['QTY'];
           $product_folder=$_POST['Folder'];
           $product_cat=$_POST['Cat'];
           $product_month=$_POST['Month'];

           $status ="Public";

            $product_code="1";
            $product_type="Coupons";

        $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);

        $fileNewNTime = time();
                $fileNewName =$User."_".$product_month."_".$fileNewNTime;

        $folderPath = "Folders/".$product_folder."/";
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];







        switch ($imageType) {


            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
                break;
        }






        move_uploaded_file($file, $folderPath. $fileNewName. ".". $ext);

        $Coupons =  $folderPath + "/"+  $fileNewName. ".". $ext;

        $CouponsNom =  $fileNewName. ".". $ext;

        $CouponThumb =$fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext;

        //$product_cat = $product_folder;

        //insert client
        mysqli_query($DBcon,"INSERT INTO Coupon_list (product_name,product_desc,product_code,product_date_exp,product_user,
                                                        product_image,product_image_thumb,product_status,product_qty,product_folder,product_cat,product_type,product_month)
        VALUES ('$fileNewName','$product_desc','$product_code','$product_date_exp','$User',
                 '$CouponsNom','$CouponThumb','$status','$product_qty','$product_folder','$product_cat','$product_type','$product_month')");

        //echo "Image Resize Successfully. to $folderPath";
            echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=1;url=Upload.php?success=1>";

    }
}


function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {


    $targetWidth =200;
    $targetHeight =200;


    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);


    return $targetLayer;
}


?>
```

I was able to fix my issue with a simple rotating script.i call it to rotate the pic and it save the name back in my database.

```
    $degrees = -270;
$path = $_GET['Folder'];
$file =$_GET['Pic'];
$fileid =$_GET['id'];

$image = $path.'/'.$file;
$imageN = $path.'/New_'.$file;
//load the image
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

//rotate the image
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

$NewImg='New_'.$file ;

//set the Content type
//header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

//display the rotated image on the browser
//imagejpeg($rotate);
imagejpeg($rotate,$imageN,100);
//free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

save stuff is here

Comment: Please show your code so folks can see if you are using **GD**, or **ImageMagick**, or **GraphicsMagick** or **php_vips** to rotate your images.

Comment: im not using anything to rotate the image. but i will edit.thx

Comment: See http://us1.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php. Unfortunately, I do not see an equivalent to the command line -auto-orient. So you will have to get the orientation and do a conditional to rotate the correct amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the image functions you are using are from GD and described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

The issue is the `Orientation` tag in the EXIF data which you are currently not respecting, so you need to read it, then act on it. There are several possibilities. Either follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3657153/2836621), or change to **ImageMagick** instead of GD and use its [orientation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) functions.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31943940/2836621).

Comment: whats odd is when i upload from files in my phone they are ok if i take a picture it uploads sideways....so confusing